# React-native Vision Camera unable to zoom in iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-vision-camera

I am unable to zoom in on ios devices. I am able to zoom in on android devices without any problem but unable to zoom on iPhones or iPads can anyone help me.

We are using react-native-vision camera
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vision-camera

```
<View style={styles.container}>
                <Camera
                    ref={camera}
                    style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
                    isActive={true}
                    photo={true}
                    orientation="portrait"
                    device={device}
                    torch={cameraFlash}
                    focusable={true}
                    enableZoomGesture={true}
                    hdr={cameraHDR}
                    lowLightBoost={cameraNightMode}
                />

                <View style={styles.captionFrame}>
                    <Image style={styles.imageStyleFrame} source={fullBodyFlip ? require('./../../../../assets/images/bfiGuide/png/dog_frame_fullbody2.png') : frameImgArray[route.params?.indexPos]} />
                </View>
            </View >
```

Answer (score 0):

Zooming does not appear to be explicitly supported by the react-native-vision-camera library, and the code you provided does not demonstrate any specific zoom-related parameters.

You might have to create custom zoom controls or think about utilising a separate library or module that supports zoom capabilities if you wish to enable zoom functionality.

Here's a general how-to for adding zoom capability to a React Native application:

Use Gesture Handling:

You can add zoom capabilities using gesture handling libraries if the library doesn't already have it built in. Pinch-to-zoom motions can be performed with the react-native-gesture-handler package.

```
import { PinchGestureHandler, State } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

const handleZoom = Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { scale: zoom } }], {
  useNativeDriver: false,
});

return (
  <PinchGestureHandler onGestureEvent={handleZoom} onHandlerStateChange={handleZoom}>
    <Animated.View style={{ flex: 1, transform: [{ scale: zoom }] }}>
      {/* Your Camera component and other UI elements */}
    </Animated.View>
  </PinchGestureHandler>
);
```